# mat-table creating columns dynamically vs static change table look

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-table

Sorry if this question is trivial, I'm very new to Angular and Web UI Kingdom

I'm currently looking at this sample project: https://github.com/marinantonio/angular-mat-table-crud

I was replacing the way the columns were created (from static to dynamic) and the table layout changed into something that is hard to read. I am having trouble understanding how/why this is happening. What makes the difference in how I created my columns? But, most importantly, how do i fix it?

**Here is what I have:**

**componnent.html:**

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let column of columns" matColumnDef="{{column.name}}">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>{{column.label}}</th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row[column.name]}} </td>
</ng-container>
```

**component.ts**

```
columns: Array<any> = [
    { name: 'id',         label: 'ID',         cell: (element: any) => `${element.id}` },
    { name: 'title',      label: 'Title',      cell: (element: any) => `${element.title}` },
    { name: 'state',      label: 'State',      cell: (element: any) => `${element.state}` },
    { name: 'url',        label: 'Url',        cell: (element: any) => `${element.url}`},
    { name: 'created_at', label: 'Created at', cell: (element: any) => `${element.created_at}`},
    { name: 'updated_at', label: 'Updated at', cell: (element: any) => `${element.updated_at}`},
]
// displayedColumns = ['id', 'title', 'state', 'url', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'actions'];
displayedColumns = this.columns.map(x => x.name).concat(['actions']);
```

I didn't touch the components.css

[image]

Comment: Try taking the spaces out of the name columns for `'url  '`, `'created_at  '`, etc.

Comment: @dmcgrandle  thanks, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution!!!

**use cdkColumnDef and cdkHeaderCellDef instead of  matColumnDef and mat-header-cell**

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let column of columns; let colIndex = index" [cdkColumnDef]="column.name">
    <mat-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef>{{ column.label }}</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *cdkCellDef="let row">{{ row[column.name] }}</mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
```

Comment: how to add icons dynamically? If I want to add icons for edit and delete, how to do that? In static it's easy but how can it be possible with generic material data-table?

Answer (score 5):

**This solution is for Angular 6+**

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let i = index; let column of columnsToDisplay" 
    matColumnDef="{{column}}">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{column | titlecase}} </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
       <span *ngIf="column !== 'action'">{{element[column]}}</span>
        <span *ngIf="column == 'action'">
          <button mat-icon-button (click)="deleteRowData(element)" 
            color="primary">
            <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
          </button>
        </span>
    </td> 
</ng-container>
```